# Angular issue inheriting scripts?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, inheritance, ng-view

This may seem like an obscure question, but I am having issues with my angular inheriting scripts via an invoke script.

The generalization for this would be as follows:

We have a custom browser that will create a button when a custom "property" is added to an input object on our webpage(where the angular resides). When that property is added (similar to class and ID), it will put a button next to the Input object.

The issue I am having is that it will only work on objects outside of the ng-view.

The code works fine if the input object is located in my main index html file (before ng-view is called).

Is there a way to make it so that the custom scripts can be inherited in, what I believe, is the controllers?

Any tips are greatly appreciated.

**EDIT: Here are some code snips that are currently being used to make this functionality possible.**

The Browser Side:

```
string invokeScript = "(function(){function i(n,t){t.parentNode.insertBefore(n,t.nextSibling)}function r(n,t){var o={scannableInputId:n.id,scannerType:t},u=document.createElement(\"span\"),f=document.createAttribute(\"class\");f.value=\"input-group-btn\";u.setAttributeNode(f);var r=document.createElement(\"button\"),s=document.createTextNode(\"scan\"),e=document.createAttribute(\"class\");e.value=\"btn btn-primary\";r.appendChild(s);r.setAttributeNode(e);r.addEventListener(\"click\",function(){window.external.notify(JSON.stringify(o))});u.appendChild(r);i(u,n)}var n=document.querySelectorAll(\"[data-barcode-scan]\");for(var t in n)n.hasOwnProperty(t)&&r(n[t],n[t].getAttribute(\"data-barcode-scan\").toLowerCase())})();";
            if (Web != null)
            {
                await Web.InvokeScriptAsync("eval",
                    new[]
                    {
                        invokeScript
                    });                    
            }
```

The Website Side:

```
<h2>
Item (Demo): <input id="scannedValueDemoTextBox"
             name="scannedValueDemoTextBox"
             ng-model="scannedValueDemo"
             type="text"
             data-barcode-scan="single"
             style="width: 200px"/>
```

The "data-barcode-scan="single" is what should trigger the button to appear, which works outside the ng-view/controllers.

Comment: This isn't really a good way to use Angular.  Angular has no way of knowing when other JavaScript functions modify the DOM directly;  if an element isn't present during angular bootstrap, angular can't manage it.  If you are manipulating the DOM completely outside angular (or without being inside a custom directive), then you are likely in a situation where you aren't using angular for the task it was created to solve.

Comment: The main reasoning for this script is to add a way for the user to access a scanning app on their phones/tablets to scan a barcode. The barcode value will then be inserted into the Input. That is the only functionality of this inserted scripts. Otherwise angular is controlling everything DOM wise.

Comment: without any code it's not really easy to give you a solution, but this sounds like a case where the code for capturing barcodes should be called from inside a directive, with `$scope.$apply()` called afterword to manually re-render the DOM elements.

Comment: I edited my code to reflect what I am doing exactly in both the custom browser as well as the website.

Comment: The main problem here is that the script is executing before angular has run, and therefore the elements that are in the `ng-view` aren't actually in the DOM to be found.  You would need to **delay** the execution of this script until after an angular digest, which is part of what putting DOM manipulating code in directives can do for you.